# Use keyboard as touchscreen input on Chromebook

Tags: keyboard, touchscreen, chromebook

I play Recharge RC on my Chromebook but I don't like using the touch screen. Is it possible to use my keyboard inputs and transfer them to touchscreen inputs?

Comment: For the moment, ChromeOS as of version 105 is testing/supporting a limited number of Android games via keyboard, but I don't see your game in particular. Source: https://techcrunch.com/2022/09/02/chromeos-is-testing-keyboard-controls-for-android-games/.